# Calculus Three divergence theorem

Tags: calculus

From definition of divergence div. E=closed integral (E.ds)/dv so to get gauss divergence theorem we get closed integral (E.ds)=div. E dv but in gauss divergence theorem theres a volume integral,so where does volume integral comes from this definition. I know we can prove divergence theorem but i want to know how does it come from the definition of divergence.

Comment: ${\rm div} \vec{E}=\lim_{r(V)\to 0}\frac{\oint E_n\, dS}{V}$, where $r(V)$ is radius of closed volume $V$, integral is taken around surface limiting closed volume $V$. Then for infinitesimal volumes ${\rm div}\vec{E}\, dV=\oint E_n\, dS$, where integral is taken around surface limiting closed infinitesimal volume $dV$. One can divide finite volume $V$ into infinitesimal volumes and do summation: then $\int_V {\rm div}\vec{E}\, dV=\oint E_n\, dS$ where integral is taken around surface limiting closed finite volume $V$. Surface integral for inner boundaries parts are compensating one another.

Comment: If we do a volume integral on left hand side then shouldnt it also be integrated in the right hand side,thats what my confusion is.